# Prove that $\Psi$ is continuous.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

Let $g:U\times V\subset \Bbb C\times \Bbb C\to \Bbb C$ a continuous function on $U\times V$ with $U\times V$ endowed with the product topology and $\gamma:[0,1]\to V$ a piecewise smooth curve on $U$. Define $\Psi:U\to \Bbb C$ by $$\Psi(z)=\int_{\gamma}g(z,w)dw$$
Prove that $\Psi$ is continuous on $U$.

**Try:** What I have to prove is that $\displaystyle \lim_{z\to a}\Psi(z)=\Psi(a)$. So, suppose $|z-a|<\delta$. Then,
$$\begin{align*}|\Psi(z)-\Psi(a)|&=\left |\int_{\gamma}g(z,w)dw-\int_{\gamma}g(a,w)dw \right |\\ 
&=\left |\int_{\gamma}(g(z,w)-g(a,w))dw \right|\\ &\le\int_{\gamma}|g(z,w)-g(a,w)||dw|\end{align*}$$

After that I want to use that $g$ is continuous in $U\times V$ in order to bound $|g(z,w)-g(a,w)|$ but I don't know how, any help.

Comment: I think you should write $\Psi(w) = \int_\gamma g(z, w)dz$ instead..

Comment: Why? The exercise is written that way not as $\Psi(w)$. @Riemann

Comment: According to your question, $\Psi:V\to\mathbb{C}$ and $\Psi(z)$ means $z\in V$, but $g(z, w)$ implies that $z\in U$. Your notations are inconsistent.

Comment: Yes, my mistake. I already corrected, the function $\Psi$ has domain $U$. @Riemann

Comment: Okay. You need to have $\gamma:[0, 1]\to V$, too.

Comment: Right, thanks. @Riemann

Comment: By the way, is $U$ a metric space?

Comment: The exercise doesn't say anything about that, they are just subsets of $\Bbb C$. @Riemann

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we further assume that $U$ is open, then it is possible to prove.

$\gamma([0, 1])$ is a continuous image of compact subset $[0, 1]$ of $\mathbb{R}$, which is also compact. Also, the set $A = \{z\in\mathbb{C}: |z-a|\le\delta\}$ is a compact subset of $U$. Hence $A\times\gamma([0, 1])$ is a compact subset of $U\times V$, so that $g$ is uniformly continuous on $A\times\gamma([0, 1])$. Hence by ML inequality, $$|\Psi(z)-\Psi(a)|\le\varepsilon\cdot L(\gamma)$$ where $\varepsilon>0$ is given and we choose $\delta>0$ s.t for $|z-a|<\delta$, $|g(z, w)-g(a, w)|<\varepsilon$ for any $w$(also choose $\delta$ so that $A\subset U$). This completes the proof.

Comment: A question. So that it was proved that $g$ is uniformly continuous in $A\times \gamma([0,1])$ I don't understand that part.

Comment: It is because $g$ is continuous on a compact set $A\times\gamma([0, 1])$. You can use the definition of compactness to prove continuous functions on a compact set is uniformly continuous.

Comment: No, i know that part. But what I'm asking is what is it used for in the future. Is it so that $|g(z,w)-g(a,w)|<\epsilon$ for any $w$?

Comment: Yes. $\delta$ can be choosen even if $|g(z, w)-g(a, w)|<\varepsilon$ for any $w$ by the uniformity.

Comment: Right, thanks for answer. I appreciated it :).